# Prove that it is not possible to assign the integers $1,2,3,\cdots,20$ to the twenty vertices of a dodecahedron so that each face have constant sum

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Prove that it is not possible to assign the integers $1,2,3,\cdots,20$
>   to the twenty vertices of a regular dodecahedron so that the five
>   numbers at the vertices of each of the twelve pentagonal faces have
>   the same sum.

That's what I have done.

Let $k$ be the constant sum of each of the twelve faces of the dodecahedron,then:
$$3(1+2+\cdots+20)=12k$$

$$3\left(\cfrac{20(1+20)}{2}\right)=12k$$

$$\cfrac{210}{4}=k$$

But $k$ is an integer,so we have a contradiction.

Is this proof correct and complete?Are there other ways to apprach the problem ?

(The problem has been taken from USAMTS 1)

Comment: I think it is correct. But I am curious about what made you doubt your solution..

Comment: I always doubt my solutions since I have no one to ask for my solutions.Also since this is a problem from usamts ,I wanted to be sure.Why?

Comment: If I were writing it on a test I would explain why 3(1+...+20)=12K, even though it's obvious to me. Well done.

Comment: Its logic and the underlying premises seem water tight. That's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine but I suggest you start by explicitly saying that

> Since each vertex appears in exactly three faces, ...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks perfect to me, I doubt there is a simpler way to approach this.